# Java.sql.SQLException: operation not allowed with Oracle procedure and mybatis

Tags: oracle, spring-boot, mybatis

I am using Mybatis with springboot to connect with an Oracle database. In that process I need to update multiple fields in bulk.

I have created a procedure to implement that functionality on the database side. When calling that procedure from the DAO layer, the following exception occurs:

> org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException:
>   Error getting generated key or setting result parameter object.
>   Cause
>   Java.sql.SQLException: operation not allowed.

```
<insert id="update" parameter="java.util.map" statement="callable">
{ call test.bulk_update_procedure(#{customerid, mode=IN , jdbcType= varchar},#{firstname, mode= IN, jdbcType= varchar},#{age,mode=IN, jdbcType=varchar})
</insert>
```

Comment: Welcome to stackOverflow. Would you mind sharing the code that you are trying to execute (the procedure call) ?

Comment: Please, add the mapping you are using.